# Umbraco Base not working in shared hosting environment

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, umbraco, radix

Whenever I try to go to a base url such as http://mysite/Base/BaseClass/BaseFunction/ I am getting an error which reads:

```
Unable to load one or more of the types in assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.51116.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'. Exceptions were thrown:
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
```

It works fine on my development machine, but I am getting this error on the shared host. Has anyone encountered this error before ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears as if you are missing an assembly that is being referenced by another assembly. It is also possible that the assembly has been overwritten by a newer or older version than is expected.